# Woocomerce - Order products by float attribute in archive pages

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, pre-get-posts, customization

I'm trying to order the products in the frontend by a float attribute (pa_od), I have this code but the order is incorrect

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'imcar_custom_product_query' );
function imcar_custom_product_query( $query ) {

    if( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'pa_od' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

    return $query;
}
```

The order don't are ASC, The first product have pa_od value 25, the second 12, the third 20.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... First of all, `$query->set( 'orderby', 'pa_od' );' will most probably do nothing. You can't order by some string and think that WordPress will guess what that is.

Here is the list of possible `orderby` values:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

If you want to order by custom field, then you have to do it this way:

```
$query->set( 'meta_key', 'pa_od' );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
$query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
```

And because you want to treat that meta value as number, then this is what you really want:

```
$query->set( 'meta_key', 'pa_od' );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
$query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
```

PS. Your function is an action, so you don't need to return anything - the returned value will be ignored anyway... So here's all the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'imcar_custom_product_query' );
function imcar_custom_product_query( $query ) {

    if( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'pa_od' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysiek for the response. 

With this code any product are listed in the category, this field is one product attribute no custom option.

Comment: WC attributes are stored as taxonomies, AFAIR. If so, then there is no way to sort by them... The only way is to use `save_post` filter and store that attribute value in custom field and then sort by that CF.